# jQuery / CSS Animation - connect different buttons and forms with line and image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a question (issue) with trying to achieve something like this:

[jQuery animate example](http://dev.orbiterstudio.com/abc/)

So when you hover buttons on left - line should be drawn between hovered button and custom form like it is doing right now but i am not able to connect image in the middle with lines on left and right hand side. Is there any better option to make animation like this? Also, is it possible to make animation from left to right when button on the left hand side is clicke?

EDIT:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/ytfrwkbs]
```

Here is link on jsfiddle but please make sure to expand width of container as this code is not responsive.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, could you please add the code that you have tried so far and perhaps put it in a jsfiddle also?

Comment: Hi - it is here now. Just please make sure that you expand container to the left otherwise code will not work as it is not responsive yet.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ytfrwkbs/

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/ytfrwkbs/1/

Comment: Hey, thanks for you help. I see you connected line on the left hand side of circle and that is great, but is it possible to add line on right hand side of circle, that will be connected to circle as well? It should be horizonal line, not vertical.

Comment: Also what I should do at the end, when both lines are connected to circle is that I change functionality so that no animation is working on hover but only on click the way that line is rendered from left to the right. Is that possible? I tried change event from "hover" to "click" and that works but still can not achieve animation that will slide from left-to-right. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want the lines to connect on click (one extra line on the right side) and separate on hover?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Lines should be always connected to circle. From both sides of circle if possible. Once connected I would like to change functionality so that when you open that page for first time - you see 1st button connected to 1st form with lines connected to circle on both sides. (that is working already, just right hand side is not connected to circle). And I want nothing to happen on "hover" state, but only on click. So, on click should be done connection like it is working now on hover, but i would animation work like this: draw left line, then cricle, then right handline

Comment: And about connecting right hand line on circle, you are probably right, I guess I should add new small horizontal line that will connect vertical line on right hand side with circle in the middle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice way of achieving what you want but with less repetitive code.

http://jsfiddle.net/ytfrwkbs/8/

Your issue was working with precise pixel measurement (hand-coding it). I've made minor changes to your html but a good way to deal with repeating structure is to get `.height()` and `.position()` of elements and creating a common code based on those:

```
$('.b1,.b2,.b3,.b4,.b5').hover(function(){
        var VerticalCenter = $(this).position().top + $(this).height()/2;
        $(".left_dash").dequeue().animate({ top: VerticalCenter },"fast");
        $(".mid_dash").dequeue().animate({top: VerticalCenter - 15, left: '-5px' },"fast");
        $(".right_dash").dequeue().animate({height: VerticalCenter - 15 },"fast");
        $(".right_e_dash").dequeue().animate({top: VerticalCenter },"fast");
        // Remove +1 if you are using an array
        $(".right_form").html(FORMS[$(this).index()+1]);
        $(".b1").css({"background-color":"white","color":"black"});
        // 30px is the size of the button + 3px for arrangement
        $(".mid_form").dequeue().animate({height: $(".right_form").height() - 33 },"fast");
        $(".b1,.b2,.b3,.b4,.b5").not(this).css({"background-color":"black","color":"white"});
});
```

Another good rule to follow is to add `.dequeue()` to your `.animate()` calls. This makes the UI more responsive as things won't get stuck in a long animation queue. Of course this queue is useful in a lot of situations but in cases like this when navigation is involved I would say dequeue is a must.

Comment: Thank you. This is definitelly something i tried to achieve. I will play with HTML / JS to get exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I found this interesting so I implemented by my self. Here is the result if it helps you

```js
var selectedContentItem = 1;
var connectOn = {
 click: "click",
 mouseover: "mouseover"
};

$(".menu-item").on(connectOn.mouseover, function() {
 var leftGuide = $("#bridgeLeftGuide");
 var middleGuide = $("#bridgeMiddleGuide");
 var rightGuide = $("#bridgeRightGuide");
 var selectedItem = $(this);
 var speed = 100;

 leftGuide.animate({
  top: selectedItem.offset().top - 2
 }, speed);

 middleGuide.animate({
  top: selectedItem.offset().top + 2 - middleGuide.height() + selectedItem.height() / 2
 }, speed);

 rightGuide.animate({
  height: selectedItem.offset().top + 2
 }, speed);

 var menuId = selectedItem.data("menu-id");

 $("#contentItemId_" + selectedContentItem).slideToggle(100 );
 $("#contentItemId_" + menuId).slideToggle(100);
 selectedContentItem = menuId;
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   }

   body {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #ddd;
   }

   img {
    max-width: 100%;
   }

   .connection-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }

   /** MENU **/
   .menu-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
   }

   .menu-item {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: relative;
    cursor: default;
   }

   .menu-item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
   }

   .menu-item:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
   }
   
   /** Content **/

   .content-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 55%;
    margin-left: 10px;
   }

   .content-wrapper-item {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: none;
   }

   .content-wrapper-item:first-of-type {
    display: block;
   }
   
   .content-wrapper:before { 
    content: "";
    width: 1px;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    height: 100%;
   }

   .content-wrapper-input{
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: .7;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-left: -5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 30%;
    border-width: 0;
   }

    /** Bridge **/ 
   .menu-content-bridge {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25%;
   }

   .bridge-left {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
   } 
  
   .bridge-left-guide {
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    height: 5px;
    top: 5%;
    width: 100%;
   }

   .bridge-middle {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
   }

   .bridge-middle-guide {
    width: 30px;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;   
    top: -8%;
   }

   .bridge-middle-guide:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 48%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 1px;
    right: -80%;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    display: block;
   }

   .bridge-right {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
   }

   .bridge-right-guide {
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
   }

   @media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .bridge-middle-guide:before {
     display: none;
    }
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="connection-wrapper">
   <div class="menu-wrapper">
    <div class="menu-item" data-menu-id="1">TEST 1</div>
    <div class="menu-item" data-menu-id="2">TEST 2</div>
    <div class="menu-item" data-menu-id="3">TEST 3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="menu-content-bridge">
    <div class="bridge-left">
     <div class="bridge-left-guide" id="bridgeLeftGuide"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bridge-middle">
     <div id="bridgeMiddleGuide" class="bridge-middle-guide">
      <img src="http://dev.orbiterstudio.com/abc/img/test.png" alt="" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bridge-right">
     <div class="bridge-right-guide" id="bridgeRightGuide"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrapper-item" id="contentItemId_1">
     <div>
      <input type="text" class="content-wrapper-input" placeholder="NAME" />
      <input type="text" class="content-wrapper-input" placeholder="EMAIL" />
      <input type="text" class="content-wrapper-input" placeholder="ZIP" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper-item" id="contentItemId_2">
     <input type="text" class="content-wrapper-input" placeholder="TEST" /><br />
     <input type="text" class="content-wrapper-input" placeholder="TEST 2" /><br />
     <input type="text" class="content-wrapper-input" placeholder="ANOTHER TEST" />
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper-item" id="contentItemId_3">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br /> consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, <br />
     consequuntur est quia nobis iure natus mollitia <br /> sapiente minus ipsa omnis  <br />
     repudiandae debitis voluptatum  <br />aspernatur incidunt praesentium quo <br /> illum esse. Sapiente! <br />
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br /> consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum,  <br />
     consequuntur est quia nobis iure natus <br /> mollitia sapiente minus ipsa omnis  <br />
     repudiandae debitis voluptatum aspernatur <br /> incidunt praesentium quo illum esse. Sapiente! <br />
    </div>
   </div>

   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ngr080r9/

Comment: Thank you. This code is usefull as well, I will check it

Comment: I dont have a lot of time now but in an hour or two I'll fix some issues that i dont like

Comment: Thank you, from what I see this code is working great except some issues with lines that cross each other, but as I am in a rush I am working on code provided above by Schahriar SaffarShargh because he used exact classes / variables I used in my project

Comment: Haha no problem. Yea that is the issue that i have to check. I gave it just as additional example